# error in compiling a c++ code in order to use it in a django project

Tags: c++, python-3.x, shared-libraries, ctypes, fpic

Recently I start a Django project in order to some image processing purposes. for some performance reasons, I wrote a function in c++ and test it independently. Now I want to call that c++ function in my python code. but when I compile it with this instruction:

```
g++ a.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -shared -o program.so
```

this error occurred:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvIlzBz.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZNK2cv7MatSizeclEv' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

according to this error, if ّ replace -shared with -fPIC flag, it compiles but at my python code, this error occurred:

```
cannot open shared object file:
```

which means that it is not compiled correctly.

finally I build the c++ program with this instruction:

```
g++ a.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -shared  -fPIC  -lm -o program.so
```

but when I execute my python code and call a function(sample_func) in that c++ code, it's give this error :

```
../program.so: undefined symbol: sample_func
```

how I can fix this problem?

Comment: @samini it just introduce another ways and don't say anything about how to solve this problem directly.

Comment: Please post your library code and the *Python* code that calls it. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Hint: are you sure that you marked the function as `extern "C"`?

Comment: @CristiFati Thank you. it's ok now. I forgot extern "C".  :)